# Data is not Updated in the List View on calling arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android

Main Activity

```
    task_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.task_list);
    elements = dbHelper.getTasks();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements);
    task_list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    dbHelper.addTasks(tasks.getText().toString());
```

Data has reached from Database to Array list but not Updated in List View 
Is there any problem in the position of  the notifying the change of data

Comment: Again .... `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` is not a magic wand which would be always "update"(whatever you mean by this) automagically

Comment: The current code doesn't even require a notifyDataSetChanged call as you set the adapter right above. This method should be called at the moment your data set has changed. From your code, I understand that you change it after you add a task. In this case, move arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); below dbHelper.addTasks(tasks.getText().toString());

Comment: *move arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); below dbHelper.addTasks(tasks.getText().toString());* **obviously this** (because is not a notifyDataSetChanged a magic wand) **will not help** ... unless he update underlaying data first

Comment: Yes, you are correct. "elements" should contain the new data in order to work.

Comment: No ... again(i wrote it bazillion times) : you should not depend on adding data to collection passed to `ArrayAdapter` ... as after you use filter then it will not works (check ArrayAdapter source mObjects vs mOriginalValues  after filltering references to original object are removed and ArrayAdapter is using the copy) ... so if you wana depend on it do not use ArrayAdapter but own Adapter based on BaseAdapter ... or using ArrayAdapter.add/remove/etc

Comment: @Selvin, interesting. I admit that I haven't used ArrayAdapter very often. In general I used my on adapter so I didn;t realize this difference.

Comment: The problem appear only if you are using filtering ... but if you don't wana use filtering then implementing BaseAdapter like [this](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/bb4f8aebb129f1db9420) should be ok without ArrayAdapter as a base class... and as you said updating elements and calling notifyDataSetChanged would be ok ... The common mistake is also storing own copy of colletion passed into  constructor and passing it also to base constructor and then using it inside getView instead getItem

Answer (score 0):

You need to call arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after adding the task and update the elements array also.

```
dbHelper.addTasks(tasks.getText().toString());
elements=dbHelper.getTasks();
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```